# Как использовать переменную как имя поля в БД

Tags: postgresql, golang, переменные

Всем привет.

```
func PostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    name := r.FormValue("name")
    newCook := time.Now().String() + name
    _, cookie1, cookie2, cookie3 := RangeCookieByUsername(w, r, name)
//RangeCookieByUsername(w, r, name) возвращает все куки для пользователя из полей cookie1, cookie2, cooki3 если username найден в базе
    currentCookie := Switching(cookie1, cookie2, cookie3) //прогоняю все значения кук для пользователя из базы в поисках шаблонного
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dbconnect)
//когда шаблонное значение найдено, пытаюсь обновить куку в определенном поле
//(имя поля вернулось из Switching), используя переменную вместо имени поля.
_, field := Switching(cookie1, cookie2, cookie3)
    rowsCookies, _ := db.Query("update AuthData set $1=$2  where username=$3", field, newCook, name)
    db.Close()
    rowsCookies.Close()
}

func Switching(c1 string, c2 string, c3 string) (string, string) {
    defaultValue := "1234567890"
    switch defaultValue {
    case c1:
        return c1, "cookie1"
    case c2:
        return c2, "cookie2"
    case c3:
        return c3, "cookie3"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

В базе есть 3 поля cookie1, cookie2, cookie3 изначально все они имеют одно шаблонное значение `1234567890` затем, когда пользователь авторизуется, происходит проверка какое из полей имеет шаблонное значение и поле с шаблонным значением должно обновится, например обрести вид текущего времени

```
time.Now().String()
```

Но обновится должно только первое встреченное поле с шаблонным значением.
Я сделал рабочую функцию Switching и прогнал через нее все три поля cookie1, cookie2, cookie3 и эта функция возвращает только одно значение(только первое встреченное шаблонное значение) и имя поля.
Вот только когда я пытаюсь применить такое у меня возникает EmptyResponse в браузере. Я подозреваю что из-за конструкции

```
 rowsCookies, _ := db.Query("update AuthData set $1=$2 where username=$3", field, newCook, name)
```

а именно из-за того, что идет после ключевого слова set. Там должно быть указано имя поля, но я пытаюсь использовать переменную в качестве имени поля. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне использовать переменную в качестве имени поля? Либо, если есть другой подход, я готов его рассмотреть.
UPD:
Я пытаюсь сделать ограничение авторизованных сессий одного пользователя.
Когда 3 раза пользователь уже авторизовался, 4 раз уже не может. Для этого используются куки, 3 шт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Связываемые переменные далеко не везде допустимы, в частности, их нельзя использовать для имен колонок. Колонки должны быть явно прописаны в запросе.

Поэтому, нужно воспользоваться форматированием строк:

```
query := fmt.Sprintf("update AuthData set %s=$1  where username=$2", field)
db.Query(query, newCook, name)
```